# How to fetch first occurance of most active row row in job table with specific deptid,

Tags: peoplesoft

Eg :  Emplid 001 most effective dated row (say 01/01/2013 )is active and belongs to deptid 101.Suppose If he has two more rows prior with same deptid say one on 10/12/2012 and 01/12/2012, Then i needs to retrieve 01/12/2012 rows.So it should be the first row of continous occurances, In case if i have row with 05/12/2012 with other deptid (102), In that case my query should return 10/12/2012 rows, Please help on this

Comment: Could you post your query?

Comment: SELECT EMPLID, MIN(EFFDT) EFFDT, DEPTID
FROM
(
    SELECT T1.EMPLID ,T1.EFFDT, T1.DEPTID, MIN(T2.EFFDT) EFFDT1
    FROM PS_JOB T1
    LEFT JOIN PS_JOB T2
    ON T1.EFFDT <= T2.EFFDT
    AND T1.DEPTID <> T2.DEPTID  
    AND T1.EMPLID <> T2.EMPLID  
    GROUP BY T1.EMPLID ,T1.EFFDT, T1.DEPTID
) X
GROUP BY EMPLID,EFFDT, DEPTID
ORDER BY 1;

Comment: Can i get answer from someone plz

Answer (score 0):

Though not with a left join, this uses a sub-select on minimum effective date to get the data you need - the trick to get the min effdt by deptid is putting the deptid in the sub-select.  Note that empl_rcd_nbr is usually used as a limiter in the sub-select (and job2.empl_rcd_nbr - job.empl_rcd_nbr) but you didn't have it in your original select.  If you get dup rows, check your empl_rcd_nbr value since it is a primary key:

```
select job.emplid, job.effdt, job.deptid
from ps_job job
where job.effdt = (select Min(job2.effdt) 
                   from ps_job job2
                   where job2.emplid = job.emplid
                     and job2.deptid = job.deptid)
order by job.emplid
```

Comment: In the example case given in the question, this query will not return the 10/12/2012 row in case a row with different deptid exists between 01/12/2012 and 10/12/2012.

Comment: @navi Sorry about that - I didn't quite understand the question - your solution makes sense as long as there ALWAYS is a prior department as well as only one different department - because there may be more than one.  It would be quite challenging to build that sql - at this point, I'd use SQR in a PeopleSoft system

Comment: True! When written in an application engine, the sql might turn out to be a big one. But that is something @Ramesh R has to figure out :P We are only here to suggest and help :D

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you need, you will have to pick up the min(effdt) row with deptid same as the deptid of the current max(effdt) row and also, there should not exist a row > the min(effdt) with deptid <> deptid of the min(effdt) row.

A query satisfying the above conditions should help you with your result set.